# How can I use Google's Vision API on images in my own website

Tags: google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, google-cloud-vision, multilabel-classification

I am very new to Google's API and machine learning in general. I want to use the Vision API labeling ability for a student project I am working on.

I would like to create a website that works similarly to the demo of the API on google's product page. I would like to be able to click on images in the website and see the labels that vision creates. If possible, I would like to use a pre-trained model like the advertising material. Additionally, if possible, I would like to be able to sort the images based on their labels in the website's interface. I attached an image of what the demo on the product page produces for reference (the image is a digital render that I created). I want to see how well the API can classify artificially created images.

I have looked through a lot of the documentation but I am not really sure where to start with all this. I also found this on [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/python/awwvision), but I am not sure how to utilize something like this for my own images. Can anyone give me some pointers?

[image]

Comment: Hey,  could you provide a link to the site you referenced for the google product page to better understand the behavior you are attempting to achieve? I am also unable to identify the "advertising material" that you referenced.

Comment: Here is the link: https://cloud.google.com/vision/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=na-US-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-dr-1009135&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_291249276637-ADGP_Hybrid+%7C+AW+SEM+%7C+BKWS+%7C+US+%7C+en+%7C+EXA+~+ML/AI+~+Vision+API+~+Google+Vision+Api-KWID_43700036257547159-kwd-475108782609&utm_term=KW_google%20vision%20api-ST_Google+Vision+Api&gclid=CjwKCAjw0_T4BRBlEiwAwoEiARB5_yYL8WaNrFcFJhnKGM0PSVrGkDStev8ckIFApfKyshp0XM6kIBoC4b8QAvD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

You can send image bytes, a path to a file in GCS or a path to a public image: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#image

It sounds like you are interested in sending the image bytes.